# What's the best way for the client app to immediately react to an update in the database?

Tags: database, ajax, triggers, rfc

What is the best way to program an immediate reaction to an update to data in a database?

The simplest method I could think of offhand is a thread that checks the database for a particular change to some data and continually waits to check it again for some predefined length of time. This solution seems to be wasteful and suboptimal to me, so I was wondering if there is a better way.

I figure there must be some way, after all, a web application like gmail seems to be able to update my inbox almost immediately after a new email was sent to me. Surely my client isn't continually checking for updates all the time. I think the way they do this is with AJAX, but how AJAX can behave like a remote function call I don't know. I'd be curious to know how gmail does this, but what I'd most like to know is how to do this in the general case with a database.

Edit:
Please note I want to immediately react to the update in the client code, not in the database itself, so as far as I know triggers can't do this. Basically I want the USER to get a notification or have his screen updated once the change in the database has been made.

Comment: wow a lot of people appear to be responding to the topic title, without actually reading the question.  Its not a trigger folks!!  If I had any votes left today I'd down vote them all to teach them a lesson to read the damn question before responding.

Comment: Well that's a bit harsh. The question was all but asking for magic. If he wants an immediate reaction, triggers are probably going to be involved somewhere in the process.

Comment: @Dana: Not its not harsh to expect people to read a question before attempting to answer.  No he is hardly asking for magic, he uses real workd example (gmail) as a model.  And no, triggers are probably NOT going to be involved.

Comment: The title is very poor.  Triggers are the correct answer to the question as posed by the title.  Further, until the edit happened, triggers were *still* the answer to "how to do this in the general case with a database."  Removing references to databases would probably help.

Comment: Actually I agree the title is poor, but I do want to know how to react to changes in data in a database in particular, but the key is to react to them in the client application. I'll see if I can come up with a better title to capture this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You basically have two issues here:

1. You want a browser to be able to receive asynchronous events from the web application server without polling in a tight loop.
2. You want the web application to be able to receive asynchronous events from the database without polling in a tight loop.

**For Problem #1**

See these wikipedia links for the type of techniques I think you are looking for:

- [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)
- [Reverse AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Ajax)
- [HTTP Server Push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#HTTP_server_push)

EDIT: 19 Mar 2009 - Just came across [ReverseHTTP](http://www.reversehttp.net/) which might be of interest for Problem #1.

**For Problem #2**

The solution is going to be specific to which database you are using and probably the database driver your server uses too.  For instance, with [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) you would use [LISTEN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-listen.html) and [NOTIFY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-notify.html).  (And at the risk of being down-voted, you'd probably use database triggers to call the NOTIFY command upon changes to the table's data.)

Another possible way to do this is if the database has [an interface](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/spi.html) to create stored procedures or triggers that link to a dynamic library (i.e., a DLL or .so file).  Then you could write the server signalling code in [C or whatever](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/triggers.html).

On the same theme, some databases allow you to write stored procedures in languages such as [Java, Ruby](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/external-pl.html), [Python](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/plpython.html) and [others](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/external-pl.html).  You might be able to use one of these (instead of something that compiles to a machine code DLL like C does) for the signalling mechanism.

Hope that gives you enough ideas to get started.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why but server push is rarely utilized well.

Answer (score 6):

> I figure there must be some way, after
>   all, web application like gmail seem
>   to update my inbox almost immediately
>   after a new email was sent to me.
>   Surely my client isn't continually
>   checking for updates all the time. I
>   think the way they do this is with
>   AJAX, but how AJAX can behave like a
>   remote function call I don't know. I'd
>   be curious to know how gmail does
>   this, but what I'd most like to know
>   is how to do this in the general case
>   with a database.

Take a peek with wireshark sometime... there's some google traffic going on there quite regularly, it appears.

Depending on your DB, triggers might help.  An app I wrote relies on triggers but I use a polling mechanism to actually 'know' that something has changed.  Unless you can communicate the change out of the DB, some polling mechanism is necessary, I would say.

Just my two cents.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the *best* way is a database [trigger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger).  Depends on the ability of your DBMS, which you haven't specified, to support them.

Re your edit: The way applications like Gmail do it is, in fact, with AJAX polling.  Install the [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966) Firefox extension to see it in action.  The trick there is to keep your polling query blindingly fast in the "no news" case.

Comment: Please see my edit above, as far as I know triggers can't do what I'm asking for.

Comment: Re your edit: This seems crazy to me because gmail has tons of clients, to have all of them polling the server all the time seems so inefficient. There's got to be a better way... But thanks for that insight, I wouldn't have thought that's how it's actually done.

Comment: The alternative, "server push", the Big New Thing That Will Revolutionize The Web of 1994 or so, involves keeping a live TCP connection for every client, which is an exponentially worse idea.

Comment: I remember the Netscape FishCam that used server push circa 1994.  Very exciting.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no way to push data to a web browser - you can only ever send data as a response to a request - that's just the way HTTP works.

AJAX is what you want to use though: calling a web service once a second isn't excessive, provided you design the web service to ensure it receives a small amount of data, sends a small amount back, and can run very quickly to generate that response.

Comment: What about for normal desktop applications with a database back-end. Is there a way to push data to the application from the database? Maybe some type of connection that stays open?

Comment: Not actually true.  Server push does work.  It's just a colossally bad idea.

Comment: Thanks chaos - I wasn't aware of that. I guess because it's such a bad idea, I've never even heard of it! :-)