# Page refresh on record in database changing

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Okay so I'm running into a small problem.

Basicly my whole website runs through the AJAX system, content is loaded in the middle page, and theres a left and right menu which dont refresh.

Currently I'm trying to look for a PHP->Ajax feature that refreshes the whole website incase a certain record changes in the MYSQL table

Okay so every user has a record called "State" which indicates the state of their account, this can be changed by anyone, for example the account gets shot and killed by someone. How do I make it so it checks what state you have and if it changes from the "standart"  state that it performs a full page refresh.

I tried to find an answer for this everywhere but haven't been able to figure something out.

-----Edit-----

Okay so I'll also notify, I kind of know how to perform a full page refresh, and I know how to retrieve data from the mysql database, this isn't the problem.

I have a table with all the users accounts in it, one of the records for every user is called "State" everybodies state will be 1 which means alive. when its 0 it means its a dead account.

On a part of my website theres an auto refresh with always fetches data from the database every 5 seconds, to check if your online if you have money etc. it also checks what state you have.

the only thing I want to do, is that when it sees your state is 0, it performs a full page refresh, considering state 0 means death, you should be seeing a deathscreen, I want it to perform a full page refresh cause the menu's have to dissapear. and it has to redirect you to the deathpage.

Comment: If you mean refresh the whole **page** (and not website), then check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194080/ajax-refresh-page-content-instead-of-div-content

Comment: I dont think your getting what I want.
I want the page to refresh when the record in the mysql database changes, the record is "state" its preset on "1" for each account, unless they get killed then the state is "0" how can I make it so that if it detects your state being changed it will refresh the whole page? (Theres an auto refresh on small part of the page, I can add the following code to this part to do the checking of the record "state"  changing.)

Comment: Is your problem how to refresh the whole page or how to get the state from the DB? Or both?

Comment: If it's the second, how to have the browser know (as soon as possible) that something (the state) in the DB has changed, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587027/whats-the-best-way-for-the-client-app-to-immediately-react-to-an-update-in-the-d

Comment: Editted my first post hopefully its more clear what I'm trying to do now.

Comment: Did you check the `setInterval()` periodic refresh?

Comment: Yeah I checked it out, however I didn't see specific full refresh on change of something in database. since I already have an auto refresh function on small part of my sity (only 1 certain div refreshes every 5 seconds which checks state) I just need to add that if state changed it fully refreshes the page.

Comment: Yes, `(pseudocode:) if (state_has_changed) then window.location.reload()`

Comment: Oooh overlooked that, thanks a lot I will try it out tonight when I'm home. thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need long pooling / comet - basically you keep open connection between the client and the server, and when the state is changed, the server sends the response to the client.

Basically, you'll open a long pooling connection, sending the userid.
The server script receives the userid, and starts monitoring for changes for that user. If such change is detected, send the response.

If performance is concern, you can use Tornado web server. What's nice about it, is that you can post from another application to the web server, and it can detect which client is affected by the change and send response to that client.

Comment: But all these options revolve around installing server intensive apps, there really isn't any code that just checks "state" and just performs a real time refresh once it notices it changed? considering on this small part that refreshes every 5 seconds, it checks if your online, how much money you have, and updates this every 5 seconds, so it really isn't possible to just put something like "if state = 0 perform 'refresh'" or anything?