# Refresh a webpage when a value is changed in an XML file

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a webpage written in PHP that changes the value of an XML file when a GET request is received. This is the PHP code:

```
<?php

   if ($_GET) {

      $central = simplexml_load_file('central.xml');
      $central->motion_sensor[0]->value = $_GET["data"];

      $central->asXML('central.xml');
      }

   $central = simplexml_load_file('central.xml');
   echo $central->motion_sensor[0]->value;
?>
```

Basically I would like the page to refresh itself automatically, showing the new value of $central->motion_sensor[0]->value when it is updated by the GET request. I thought about JavaScript to do that but I don't really know how to implement. If anyone could help, that would be great !

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to refresh the page *only* when the XML is updated. Is it a problem to just have the page update every [x] seconds/minutes?

Comment: Yes, that would be much more efficient and clean to update it only when the XML is updated. It is data from sensors so I only want to update when a sensor changes its state.

Comment: It's theoretically possible, have a look at these two questions on Stack Overflow: [How can I refresh a page when a database is updated?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4629642/1045794) AND [Page refresh on record in database changing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7058994/1045794) BUT bear in mind both have their own (pros and) cons. I'd recommend having a play about with them & then asking a new question once you hit a wall.